# Openerp Timer task using python Threads

Tags: python, xml, multithreading, odoo

Please can anyone give me a example for OpenERP [python] threads.
my requirement is Need to read attendance [text based file] hourly and store it and backup

i searched in forums & workspace also for example but still didn't get any
please help me

thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you won't find any example because it's not the way of doing it. just use Schedulers, and that will do the trick.

Cheers,
Parthiv

Comment: thanks dear Parthiv
then how to add schedule.? using python code or by create new module.?

Comment: check how MRP scheduler and email queue scheduler work. just a simple function in the system and a configuration in scheduler list.